# Shared memory between 2 processed (application crushed)

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm trying to share a `pandas.DataFrame` between 2 process by using `multiprocessing.shared_memory` module.

I started with opening 2 notebooks with `JupyterLab` and I wrote that code:

[image: Notebook 1]

[image: Notebook 2]

To be able to use `copy` and `paste` I will post the code as a text too:

```
# Notebook 1:

from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

values = lambda cast: [cast(value) for value in range(5)]

pd_object = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': values(cast=int), 'B': values(cast=float), 'C': values(cast=str)})
np_object = pd_object.to_numpy(copy=True, dtype='object')

shared_memory = SharedMemory(name='dataframe', create=True, size=np_object.nbytes)
shared_object = np.ndarray(shape=np_object.shape, dtype=np_object.dtype, buffer=shared_memory.buf)

shared_object[:] = np_object
shared_object
# array([[0, 0.0, '0'],
#        [1, 1.0, '1'],
#        [2, 2.0, '2'],
#        [3, 3.0, '3'],
#        [4, 4.0, '4']], dtype=object)

shared_memory.close()
shared_memory.unlink()

# Notebook 2:

from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

shared_memory = SharedMemory(name='dataframe')
shared_object = np.ndarray(shape=(5, 3), dtype=np.object, buffer=shared_memory.buf)

shared_object # here the application crushed without no reason...

pd_object = pd.DataFrame(data=shared_object, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object')
pd_object = pd_object.astype(dtype={'A': 'int64', 'B': 'float64', 'C': 'object'})

shared_memory.close()
```

The problem is the application is crushed on `Notebook 2` where I'm asking to view the output of `shared_object`, I don't know why it happens...

I tried to follow this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html)

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory arrays can't have object types. Object type arrays are pointer arrays - the pointers are going to be completely invalid in a new shell, and python is going to segfault when it tries to access them.

Switch to a numeric dtype.

Comment: How can I share a mixing types of DataFrame? like this example that include (int, float and str)

Comment: You could share the non string columns as separate arrays. If you want to use this dataframe as is you should look into other ways of doing interprocess communication.